# Why TFBertForTokenClassification.from_pretrained("allenai/scibert_scivocab_uncased",from_pt=True,config=config) gives weights warning?

Tags: pytorch, tensorflow2.0, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, allennlp

I want to do Named Entity Recognition on scientific articles.

```py
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('allenai/scibert_scivocab_cased')
model=TFBertForTokenClassification.from_pretrained("allenai/scibert_scivocab_uncased",from_pt=True,config=config)
```

But it gives following warning.

> Some weights of the PyTorch model were not used when initializing the
> TF 2.0 model TFBertForTokenClassification: ['classifier.weight',
> 'classifier.bias'] - This IS expected if you are initializing
> TFBertForTokenClassification from a TF 2.0 model trained on another
> task or with another architecture (e.g. initializing a
> BertForSequenceClassification model from a TFBertForPretraining
> model). - This IS NOT expected if you are initializing
> TFBertForTokenClassification from a TF 2.0 model that you expect to be
> exactly identical (initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model
> from a TFBertForSequenceClassification model). Some weights or buffers
> of the PyTorch model TFBertForTokenClassification were not initialized
> from the TF 2.0 model and are newly initialized:
> ['cls.predictions.transform.dense.weight',
> 'cls.predictions.decoder.bias',
> 'cls.predictions.transform.LayerNorm.weight',
> 'cls.predictions.transform.LayerNorm.bias',
> 'cls.predictions.decoder.weight', 'cls.seq_relationship.weight',
> 'cls.predictions.bias', 'cls.predictions.transform.dense.bias',
> 'cls.seq_relationship.bias'] You should probably TRAIN this model on a
> down-stream task to be able to use it for predictions and inference.

And when I try to fit the model, it gives follwing warning.

> WARNING:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables
> ['tf_bert_for_token_classification/bert/pooler/dense/kernel:0',
> 'tf_bert_for_token_classification/bert/pooler/dense/bias:0'] when
> minimizing the loss.

Does anyone know why it is giving these warnings?

Comment: The model doesn't have any pretrained output weights for token classification and this layers will be initialized with random weights (i.e. different outpt everytime you load it). You need to train the model for your classification task before you can use it properly.

Comment: Thank you so much. And when I am trying to fit the model: history = model.fit(train_ds, epochs=1, validation_data=devel_ds), it shows this warning: WARNING:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables ['tf_bert_for_token_classification/bert/pooler/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_bert_for_token_classification/bert/pooler/dense/bias:0'] when minimizing the loss. Can you please tell why it is giving this warning?

Comment: When you are not using the pooler layer during the forward pass, you won't have gradients for the backward pass. The warning ist telling you: 'Hey I'm adjusting every weights except of ...pooler... because you haven't used it.'